# Changing a div's height with javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a 100% width 3px height div grow in height when I hover over a breadcrumb and I'm failing miserably. Here is the script:

```
var menuIsOpen = false;
function bc_MouseOver() {
    if (!menuIsOpen)
    {
        menuIsOpen = true;
        for (var int = 4; int == 20; int++)
        {
            document.getElementById("navmenu").style.height = int + "px";
        }
    }
}
```

and a bit of the html (using MVC):

```
<body>
    <div id="navigation">
        <ul id="navlist">
            <li class="titleli">
                <a href="/" target="_self" id="titlelink">Some Title</a>
            </li>
            <li class="breadcrumb" onmouseover="bc_MouseOver()">Projects</li>
            <li class="breadcrumb"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="navmenu"> </div>
    <div class="container">
        @RenderBody() 
   </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Failing how exactly, you have to tell us what it is that's not working?

Comment: Try with `int <= 20;` instead of `int == 20;` in your for loop

Comment: Do you mean `for (var int = 4; int < 20; int++)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why aren't you using CSS for this? Using a :hover pseudo-class, or applying a class on hover to an element with a transition would seem like the best answer for this, but, if you're keen on JS:

```
for (var int = 4; int == 20; int++)
{
  document.getElementById("navmenu").style.height = int + "px";
}
```

This block is synchronous, the new height wont get applied til (probably) the end of the next tick, whereby it will simply apply a height of '20px'.

You'd have to work out a way of applying a 1px increase each tick to make sure it has rendered and then opened. [jQuery animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) is pretty useful to save you having a work it all out (and solve any potential cross-browser issues) but if you're keen on vanilla JS:

```
var time = 0;
function bc_mouseOver( i ) {
  var i = i || 4;
   if ( i < 21 ) {
    document.getElementById("navmenu").style.height = int + "px";
    setTimeout( function() {
        bc_mouseOver( i + 1 )
    }, time );
  }
}
```

You might have to check that bc_mouseOver is in scope because the setTimeout will be run in the context of the window. Using [lodash/underscore defer](http://lodash.com/docs#defer) method is a good way to hide the the setTimeout and the context shifting and generally makes things much neater and more reliable.

You might have to change the variable `time` as well to get exactly what you want, I've done a 0 timeout here to force it on the next tick but that might be too quick, particularly in some environments/platforms.

Really though, this can (adn probably should) be done in a few lines of CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with your test condition in for loop. It fails everytime and loop is not executed.

Change it to:

```
 for (var int = 4; int <= 20; int++) {
        document.getElementById("navmenu").style.height = int + "px";
    }
```